# Why don't I get the same power factor?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Been trying to get out two matching power factors (p.f) from the following circuit Calculation,
[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Been working on it for 8 hours in total.  Used matlab to minimize my error and so on. But I keep getting  a differnece...

Comment: The frequency is 60 Hz.

Comment: For \$60\: \text{Hz}\$, I get \$100\:\Omega\mid\mid\left(5\:\Omega+10\:\text{mH}\right) = 4.88451729 + 3.41501831j= 5.95993785\: \angle 34.959385^\circ\$.

Comment: Even for such a small differnece the end result between the two p.f dosen't match unfourtunetly.

Comment: Please rotate your photos.

Comment: @Zeclot What is the power and power factor for \$R_1\$? (It should be obvious.) The voltage across \$R_1\$ is the same as the voltage across the \$R_2+L\$ leg. But the voltage across both these two legs is \$120.0\:\text{V}_\text{RMS}\:\angle0^\circ\$, isn't it?

Comment: Added a pictures and text below

Comment: You forgot to multiply by -j.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem. I used P=V*I instead of V*I' ('= conjugate). So the angle became wrong and gave extra errors.

Comment: You can edit your question. Please delete this because it is not answer and edit your question with these pics.

Comment: How is this an "Answer" to your question?

Comment: I did a comment on the problem. But when I added the new pictures it turned in to an answer. But solved the problem.  Had a conjugate problem when calculating the power